# dynamic jQuery Mobile SelectMenu is prematurely styling

Tags: jquery-mobile, knockout.js

Knockout is dynamically adding a select menu to a jQuery Mobile page. When it appears it has some select menu styling even though it hasn't been initialized as one. This causes a problem when I do initialize it because then it is wrapped in an extra `ui-select`. What is causing this and how can I fix it?

Here is an example. Check 'show options' to display the select. Then click one of the buttons to see the problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/5udqV/1/

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your fiddle, the select is not dynamic, only the options within the select are. So one thing you could do is in the markup add data-role="none" to the select so that jQM does not touch it during page initialization.  Then when you call `.selectmenu()` it will look right.

> Your updated **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/5udqV/2/)**

UPDATE:

Use proper jQM structure and events:

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/5udqV/3/)**

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1">
    <div data-role="header">
         <h1>My page</h1> 
    </div>
    <div role="main" class="ui-content">show options
        <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: showOptions" />
        <br />
        <div data-bind="if: showOptions">
            <select data-bind="options: options, value: selectedOption"></select>
        </div>
        <button id="a">create select</button>
        <button id="b">refresh select</button>
        <button id="c">create page</button>
        <div data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($root)"></div>
    </div>
</div>

var vm = {
    options: ["A", "B", "C"],
    showOptions: ko.observable(),
    selectedOption: ko.observable("B")
};
ko.applyBindings(vm);

$(document).on("pagecreate", "#page1", function () {
    $('button').on("click", function () {
        var id = $(this).prop("id");
        if (id == "a") {
            $("select").selectmenu();
        } else if (id == "b") {
            $("select").selectmenu("referesh");
        } else if (id == "c") {
            $(".ui-page").trigger("create");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: It's dynamic in the sense that, because of the `if` binding on the parent, it does not exist on the page until `showOptions` is true.

Comment: I see that now, you are correct. If you structure the jQM page and use the jQM events: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/5udqV/3/ the dynamic select is created without jQM enhancement. Calling selectmenu() then works.

Comment: My demo seems to work just like yours whenever the jsFiddle JavaScript setting on mine is set to _No wrap - in <body>_ instead of _onLoad_. Why does jQuery Mobile style the `select` as soon as it appears when the setting is _onLoad_?